# AWK doesn't update record with new separator

Tags: awk

I'm a bit confused with awk (I'm totally new to awk)

```
find static/*

static/conf
static/conf/server.xml
```

my goal is to romove 'static/' from the result
First step:

```
find static/* | awk -F/ '{print $(0)}'
static/conf
static/conf/server.xml
```

Same result. I expected it. Now deleting the first part:

```
 find static/* | awk -F/ '{$1="";print $(0)}'
 conf
 conf server.xml
```

thats nearly good, but I don't now why the delimiter is killed
But I can deal with it just adding the delimiter to the output:

```
find static/* | awk -F/ '{$1="";OFS=FS;print $(0)}'
 conf
/conf/server.xml
```

OK now I'm completley lost.
Why is a '/' on the second line and not on the first? In both cases I deleted the first column.

Any explanations, ideas.
BTW my preferred output would be

```
conf
conf/server.xml
```

Addendum: thank you for your kind answers. they will help me to fix the problem. 
However I want to understand why the first '/' is deleted in my last try. To make it a bit clearer:

```
find static/* | awk -F/ '{$1="";OFS="#";print $(0)}'
 conf
^ a space and no / ?
#conf#server.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I don't now why the delimiter is killed.

Whenever you redefine a field in awk using a statement like:

```
$n = new_value
```

awk will rebuild the current record `$0` and automatically replace all field separators defined by `FS`, by the output field separator `OFS` (see below). The default value of `OFS` is a single space. This implies the following:

- **`awk -F/ '{$1="";print $(0)}'`**

  The field separator `FS` is set to a single <slash>-character. The first field is reset to `""` which enables the re-evaluation of `$0` by which all regular expression matches corresponding to `FS` are replaced by the string `OFS` which is currently a single space.
- **`awk -F/ '{$1="";OFS=FS;print $(0)'`**

  The same action applies as earlier. However, after the re-computation of `$0`, the output field separator `OFS` is set to `FS`. This implies that from record 2 onward, you will not replace `FS` with a space, but with the value of `FS`.

**Possible solution with same ideology**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{$1=""}{print substr($0,2)}'
```

The substring function `substr` is needed to remove the first `/`

---

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The awk utility shall interpret each input record as a sequence of fields where, by default, a field is a string of non- <blank> non- <newline> characters. This default <blank> and <newline> field delimiter can be changed by using the `FS` built-in variable or the `-F` sepstring option. The awk utility shall denote the first field in a record `$1`, the second `$2`, and so on. **The symbol `$0` shall refer to the entire record; setting any other field causes the re-evaluation of `$0`**. Assigning to `$0` shall reset the values of all other fields and the `NF` built-in variable.
>
> **Variables and Special Variables**
>
> References to nonexistent fields (that is, fields after `$NF`), shall evaluate to the uninitialized value. Such references shall not create new fields. However, assigning to a nonexistent field (for example, `$(NF+2)=5`) shall increase the value of `NF`; create any intervening fields with the uninitialized value; and **cause the value of `$0` to be recomputed, with the fields being separated by the value of `OFS`**. Each field variable shall have a string value or an uninitialized value when created. Field variables shall have the uninitialized value when created from `$0` using `FS` and the variable does not contain any characters.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX standard: awk utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

Be aware that the default field separator `FS=" "` has some special rules

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps to understand the behaviour.1

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU find you don't need awk at all.

```
$ find static/ -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\n'
conf
conf/server.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Considering that in your output word static will come only once if this is the case try. I am simply making field separator as string `static/` for lines and printing the last field of lines then which will be after word `static/`.

```
find static/* | awk -F'static/' '{print $NF}'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding a more generic solution here. Which will match values from very first occurrence of `/` to till last of the line and while printing it will not printing starting `/`.

```
find static/* | awk 'match($0,/\/.*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reset the first field value the field is still there. Just remove the initial `/` chars after that with `sub(/^\/+/, "")` (where `^\/+` pattern matches one or more `/` chars at the start of the string):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="/"} {$1="";sub(/^\/+/, "")}1'
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/0j3JfG):

```
s="static/conf
static/conf/server.xml"
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="/"} {$1="";sub(/^\/+/, "")}1' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
conf
conf/server.xml
```

Note that with `BEGIN{OFS=FS="/"}` you set the input/output field separator just once at the start, and `1` at the end triggers the default line print operation.